# DiffTech: Differencing similar technologies in computer science (e.g. MySQL VS PostgreSQL)

Tags: app, website

**Screenshot**
[image: Home page]
[image: Comparison results of MySQL VS PostgreSQL]

**About**

Developers can use different technologies for many software development tasks in their work. However, when faced with several technologies with comparable functionalities, it is not easy for developers to select the most appropriate one, as comparisons among technologies are time-consuming by trial and error.

Instead, developers can resort to expert articles, read official documents or ask questions in Q&A sites for technology comparison, but it is opportunistic to get a comprehensive comparison as online information is often fragmented or contradictory.

To overcome these limitations, we propose the diffTech system that exploits the crowd-sourced discussions from **Stack Overflow**, and assists technology comparison with an informative summary of different comparison aspects.

**Website**

[https://difftech.herokuapp.com](https://difftech.herokuapp.com/)

**Contact**

Any questions or comments? Please leave a message in this post or email huangyi3440@gmail.com.